# Whats the Blue Square in Dragonball Fighters Z?

Tags: dragon-ball-fighterz

In Dragonball Fighters Z what does the blue square mean? I know that the pink square is for win rate but I recently saw a blue square and was confused?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square colors mean win rate. Blue is the worst win rate possible.
While white square mean not enough information, rest are like this:

blue > green > dark green > yellow > red > orange > pink

Comment: ah lol now I feel dumb, guess maybe thats why I crushed the guy thanks.

Comment: Yamcha would know about having a blue square :D